# Node.js - Asynchronous JSON query (probably easy fix)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I am new to Javascript and Node.js really hurts my head because it is asynchronous.

My goal is to query for a JSON object from an API and be able to work with it. I have *tried* to look for questions and answers on what I should be doing but none of it really makes sense to me, so I am hoping to learn by just seeing proper code.

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'url here';
var temp;
var done = false;

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
      temp = body;
      done = true;
      console.log(temp);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

if (done){
  console.log(temp);
}
```

Can someone please walk me through the proper way to restructure my code?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Does your posted code actually work? If so, are you looking for an explanation of _why_ or _how_ it works?

Comment: My code currently does *not* work, it stalls and then returns an error in Terminal: {"status": {"message": "Service unavailable", "status_code": 503}}

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I think your question would be best received on Stack Overflow, where they help troubleshoot non-working code. Please do include the error code(s) and all details. Once your code works, you are welcome to post your working code for review and we can help you improve it!

Comment: your call to `request(url /*...*/)` does not call the callback function right away - which is the async part that may be confusing. The code then goes on to check `done` which will most likely always be false because it was never set by the successful request. Whatever code you want to run on success can go in that callback function or can be called from it (via being wrapped in another function).

Answer (score 0):

According to error **{"status": {"message": "Service unavailable", "status_code": 503}}** your code is working alright but problem is in server because server is overloaded at the moment and it cannot handle more requests so it going in your callback and printing error msg .
And another thing, code after callback function will never run because done will always be false.

```
if (done){
  console.log(temp);
}
```